# mean stack error "unexpected token # json at position 0"

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I want to add `{follow}` function to my app by taking the name of the person from the url.

But I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at createStrictSyntaxError (C:\Users\hathefa\Desktop\prozad\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:157:10)
>       at parse (C:\Users\hathefa\Desktop\prozad\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
>       at C:\Users\hathefa\Desktop\prozad\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
>       at invokeCallback (C:\Users\hathefa\Desktop\prozad\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
>       at done (C:\Users\hathefa\Desktop\prozad\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
>       at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\hathefa\Desktop\prozad\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:160:13)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)

I don't know what the problem is.

This is the HTML code:

```
<form  class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" (submit)="follow()">

                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block"  [disabled]="FlowwersBy.indexOf(myUsername) > -1"> Follow</button>
                            </form>
```

This is the Angular code:

```
follow(){
    this.authService.follow(this.username).subscribe(data =>{
      if(!data.success){
        this.messageClass = 'alert alert-danger'; // Set bootstrap error class
        this.message = data.message; // Set error message
        console.log('no');
      }else{
        this.messageClass = 'alert alert-success'; // Set bootstrap error class
        this.message = data.message; // Set error message
        console.log('yes');

      }
    });
  }
```

This is the Service code:

```
follow(user){
  this.createAuthenticationHeaders(); // Create headers before sending to API
  return this.http.put(this.domain + '/authentication/follow/',user, this.options).map(res => res.json());
}
```

This is the Node code:

```
router.put('/follow',(req,res)=>{
    if(!req.body.username){
      res.json({success:false,message:'user not provided'});
      console.log(req.body.username);
    }else{
      User.findOne({username:req.body.username},(err,user)=>{
        if(!user){
          res.json({success:false,message:'user not found'});
        }else{
          if(!req.body.follower){
            res.json({success:false , message:'no follower provided'});
          }else{
            User.findOne({username:req.decoded.username},(err,follow)=>{
              if(!follow){
                res.json({success:false,message:'no follower was provided'});
              }else{
                if(user.FlowwersBy.includes(follow.username)){
                  res.json({success:false , message:"you alraedy follow him"});
                }else{

                  User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id,
                  {
                    $push:{FlowwersBy:follow.username},
                    $inc:{Flowwers:1}
                  },
                  {
                    new: true
                  },
                  function(err,user){
                    if(err){
                      res.json({success:false, message:err});
                    }else{
                      //
                        User.findByIdAndUpdate(follow._id,
                        {
                          $push:{FlowwingBy:user.username},
                          $inc:{Flowwing:1}
                        },
                        {
                          new: true
                        },
                        function(err,follower){
                          if(err){
                            res.json({success:false, message:err});
                          }else{

                            res.json({success:true, message:'done'});
                            //res.json({user});
                          }
                        }
                      )
                      //
                    }
                  }
                )

                }
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

This is the authorization code:

/* ================================================
  MIDDLEWARE - Used to grab user's token from headers
  ================================================ */

```
 router.use((req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.headers['authorization']; // Create token found in headers
    // Check if token was found in headers
    if (!token) {
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'No token provided' });  // Return error
    } else {
      // Verify the token is valid
      jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
        // Check if error is expired or invalid
        if (err) {
          res.json({ success: false, message: 'Token invalid: ' + err }); // Return error for token validation
        } else {
          req.decoded = decoded; // Create global variable to use in any request beyond
          next(); // Exit middleware
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

when i test the back-end with postman it work it.

when i open the dev tool the Networking tab.
This is the headers :

```
General:
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/authentication/follow/
Request Method: PUT
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1085
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 05 May 2018 06:11:42 GMT
Vary: Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Powered-By: Express
Request Headers:
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ar,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7
authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI1YWVjMWYwMzE2NDEwMzI3YmNkMmRiYmQiLCJpYXQiOjE1MjU1MDA0MjYsImV4cCI6MTUyNTU4NjgyNn0.ivwk4xWUJLNsYjx2lcV4U7JMO1Z8HOV-m-yNizIxiDk
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 4
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/user/meme
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
Request Payload:
meme
```

and this is the URL:

http://localhost:4200/user/meme

I solve the error the problem was that the variable that i was sending to the back-end was not json type, i figure it out after i used the Networking dev tool in chrome, thanks "Kalamarico" for your advice.

Here is the fixed code:

```
follow(username){
  this.createAuthenticationHeaders(); // Create headers before sending to API
  return this.http.put(this.domain + '/authentication/follow/',JSON.stringify({username}), this.options).map(res => res.json());
}
```

All i did was  converting the variable into json object.

Hope that you we learn from my mistake .

Comment: sounds like something expects a json but gets something else (something starting with #)

Comment: Check in the devtools the response of the request and paste in the question the result (headers and response body)

Comment: I solve the error the problem was that the variable that i was sending to the back-end was not json type, i figure it out after i used the Networking dev tool in chrome, thanks "Kalamarico" for your advice.